# Abstract title with eisvogel template

Tags: koma-script, pandoc, abstract, eisvogel

I am creating a PDF document with Pandoc using the eisvogel template. It does not print the Abstract title. I added it to the meta-data, but I believe it is not used with LaTeX. This is the minimum example:

````
---
title: "My Example document"
author:
 - Luís
language: en-IE
autoSectionLabels: true
listings: true
abstract-title: "Abstract"
abstract: |
   This is an example document to test stuff with Pandoc. In this case the goal
   is to understand when or why is the Abstract title portrayed.
...

# Example Section

Once upon a time.

```{#lst01 .c caption="A listing."}
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <generated/utsrelease.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
```
````

#### Default LaTeX template

With the default template the output is the expected.

```
pandoc --number-sections -o example.pdf example.txt
```

[image]

#### Eisvogel template

Applying the eisvogel template the Abstract title disappears. How can I get it back?

```
pandoc --number-sections --template eisvogel -o example.pdf example.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, your document uses the `scrartcl` class. You can switch on an abstract title with the `abstract` class option:

````
---
title: "My Example document"
author:
 - Luís
language: en-IE
autoSectionLabels: true
listings: true
abstract-title: "Abstract"
abstract: |
   This is an example document to test stuff with Pandoc. In this case the goal
   is to understand when or why is the Abstract title portrayed.
classoption:
- abstract
---

# Example Section

Once upon a time.

```{#lst01 .c caption="A listing."}
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <generated/utsrelease.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
```
````

[image]

Comment: Fails with the error below. Another thing: any chance of centering the title as
in the default template? 

```
YAML parse exception at line 11, column 0,
while parsing a block mapping:
did not find expected key
```

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Did you fix the wrong syntax of `...`? Note that I replaced them with `---` in my answer

Comment: This new formulation is successful indeed.